# Hortonworks webhdfs i try to list all folder it will work on Hortonworks console using curl command but not in C#

Tags: c#, hadoop, webhdfs

I try to list the name of the folder using webhdfs in C#. URL working fine using curl in sandbox but not in C# in my laptop

Error Message-
SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Uri myUri = new Uri("http://hostname:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/hive/warehouse");
    string userName = "myuser";

    WebHDFSClient hdfsClient = new WebHDFSClient(myUri, userName);
    string strDirectoryPath= "/user/hive/warehouse";
    ArrayList l = new ArrayList();
    l.Add(hdfsClient.GetDirectoryStatus(
      strDirectoryPath).Result.Directories);
}
```

Comment: Stupid test first: can you `curl` from your laptop? I would not be surprised if there was a firewall blocking your access to the WebHDFS service...

Comment: i am running curl on sandbox not on laptop, but C# i am running from laptop visual studio

Comment: OK, so you did not understand what I meant. Second attempt: Try. Running. `curl`. From. Your. Laptop. To check out network connectivity issues.

Answer (score 0):

few issues:

1. your URI is "http://hostname:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/hive/warehouse", and your strDirectoryPath= "/user/hive/warehouse" - so your duplicating the path to be "http://hostname:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/hive/warehouse/user/hive/warehouse" which does not exist
2. you user "myuser" may not have permissions access to /user/hive/warehouse - check its permissions by "hdfs dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse"
3. (just checking) the 'hostname' in the URI - is just for the question and not in the actual code, right? you'll need the hostname/ip of the sandbox